# Getting count of results in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to get the count of records from database.

In my table this is the values:

```
id  emp_id  number  created_emp_id  status  timestamp
29  7   1   2   0   2012-09-24 15:18:28
30  16  1   2   0   2012-09-24 15:18:28
31  7   2   2   0   2012-09-24 15:18:54
32  19  2   2   0   2012-09-24 15:18:54
```

i have `created_emp_id` as `2`.

So the result i needed her is 2.

That means the `number` is a repeated column.

This is the code i wrote for getting result:

`$result = $this->TravancoDSRGroup->find('all', array('conditions' => array('created_emp_id= '.$emp_id),'fields' => array('DISTINCT TravancoDSRGroup.number')));`

The `$result` return the two rows only.

But i need to get the count of this query....

Like...

`$dsrPageCnt = $this->TravancoDSRGroup->find('count',................`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$dsrPageCnt = $this->TravancoDSRGroup->find('count', array('conditions' => array('created_emp_id= '.$emp_id),'fields' => array('DISTINCT TravancoDSRGroup.number')));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1020/find-count

Comment: it return the number of record, also you can search into the array result for example all TravancoDSRGroup with a foreach and a counter